# deploy Typescrpit+Node.js server to render.com

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, deployment, render.com

***i am trying to deploy my TS+Node.js to render.com and it shows :***

`Jun 26 01:51:02 PM  ==> Starting service with 'node app.ts' Jun 26 01:51:02 PM  internal/process/esm_loader.js:74 Jun 26 01:51:02 PM      internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException( Jun 26 01:51:02 PM                                ^ Jun 26 01:51:02 PM   Jun 26 01:51:02 PM  TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /opt/render/project/src/app.ts Jun 26 01:51:02 PM      at Loader.defaultGetFormat [as _getFormat] (internal/modules/esm/get_format.js:71:15) Jun 26 01:51:02 PM      at Loader.getFormat (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:104:42) Jun 26 01:51:02 PM      at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:242:31) Jun 26 01:51:02 PM      at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:176:17) Jun 26 01:51:02 PM      at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5) { Jun 26 01:51:02 PM    code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION' Jun 26 01:51:02 PM  }

**this is my package json**

```
{   "name": "server",   "version": "1.0.0",   "description": "",   "main": "app.ts",   "scripts": {     "start": "ts-node-dev app.ts",     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"   },   "keywords": [],   "author": "",   "license": "ISC",   "devDependencies": {     "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",     "@types/cookie-session": "^2.0.44",     "@types/cors": "^2.8.13",     "@types/express": "^4.17.17",     "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.1",     "@types/node-cron": "^3.0.7",     "express": "^4.18.2",     "nodemon": "^2.0.22",     "ts-node": "^10.9.1",     "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",     "typescript": "^5.0.3"   },   "dependencies": {     "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.7.0",     "@types/joi": "^17.2.3",     "axios": "^1.4.0",     "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",     "cloudinary": "^1.37.0",     "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",     "cookie-session": "^2.0.0",     "cors": "^2.8.5",     "dotenv": "^16.0.3",     "joi": "^17.9.1",     "joi-objectid": "^4.0.2",     "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",     "mongodb": "3.6",     "mongoose": "^7.0.3",     "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",     "node-cron": "^3.0.2"   } }`
```

***this is my ts.config :***

```
{   "compilerOptions": {    "module": "commonjs",    "esModuleInterop": true,    "target": "es6",    "strict": true,    "moduleResolution": "node",    "sourceMap": true,    "outDir": "dist"  },   "include": ["app.ts"],   "exclude": ["node_modules"] }
```

Comment: You have put `"main": "app.ts"`. Render is trying to run `node .` and unable to read the Typescript file. Either change main to the output (something like "dist/app.js") or you could tell render to run another scrpt when trying to start the application.

Comment: (something like "dist/app.js" ) i tried this but its not finding app.js beacuse it name is app.ts

Comment: can you help me ? i got discord or you prefer on the phone

Comment: Are you building the app before trying to start it on render?

Answer (score 1):

Your TypeScript code needs to be compiled into JavaScript. You can either compile it on our local device or let Render do this for you.

Update the key `scripts` in your `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node-dev app.ts",
    "build": "tsc"
}
```

In the Render Service Settings add a Build Command...

```
npm install && npm run build
```

... and add a Start Command (in your case it's 'dist' as declared in your 'tsconfig')

```
node dist/server.js
```

❗ Also, make sure you don’t set the Environment Variable `NODE_ENV` to 'production', or else `npm i` won’t install typescript, and `tsc` will fail.